# In Aleinu, why can we bow?

Tags: halacha, bowing-kneeling, aleinu-leshabeiach

In Berachos 34a it says that we shouldn't bow in prayer except for during the recitation of the first blessing and Modim of the Shemoneh Esrei:

> ת"ר אלו ברכות שאדם שוחה בהן באבות תחלה וסוף בהודאה תחלה וסוף
>
> Our Rabbis taught: These are the benedictions in saying which one bows
> [in the Tefillah]: The benediction of the patriarchs, beginning and
> end, and the thanksgiving, beginning and end.

Given that is so, why do many customarily bow during the recitation of Aleinu?

Comment: That regulation is limited to shemoneh esrei

Comment: The Gra in OC siman 56 says it applies to Kaddish as well. I heard a shiur that said some say it applies to Aleinu as well.

Comment: I'm more confused why people feel it's necessary to bow during Aleinu

Comment: @Nahum The Shulchan Arukh OC 281 doesn't hold that way

Comment: The fact that you can bow in middle if bracha in shmonei esrei seems to contradict that gemara. (Acc to rema)

Comment: @Shlomy Limited to beg and end שולחן ערוך אורח חיים קי"ג:א'
אֵלּוּ בְּרָכוֹת שֶׁשּׁוֹחִין בָּהֶם: בְּאָבוֹת תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף, וּבְהוֹדָאָה תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף; וְאִם בָּא לִשְׁחוֹת בְּסוֹף כָּל בְּרָכָה, אוֹ בִּתְחִלָּתָהּ, מְלַמְּדִין אוֹתוֹ שֶׁלֹּא יִשְׁחֶה; אֲבָל בְּאֶמְצָעִיתָן, יָכוֹל לִשְׁחוֹת

Comment: @Nahum your asking on why i said acc to rema? Not on first part. On 2nd part rema learns pshat in that genara since adding to chazal takanas.

Comment: @DoubleAA Apparently there are two separate laws vis a vis bowing. One re 18 and one re הודאה specifically. The questioner didn't ask from the latter but rather from the former which is what I responded to. See Taz 113:4 who explicates these two dinim and accounts for the הודאה aspect in עלינו.

Comment: @Nahum the questioner was asking from 34b which says its miguna to bow by hallel and benching.

Comment: He quoted 34a which reads as follows
תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: אֵלּוּ בְּרָכוֹת שֶׁאָדָם שׁוֹחֶה בָּהֶן: בָּאָבוֹת תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף, בְּהוֹדָאָה תְּחִלָּה וָסוֹף. וְאִם בָּא לָשׁוּחַ בְּסוֹף כָּל בְּרָכָה וּבְרָכָה וּבִתְחִלַּת כָּל בְּרָכָה וּבְרָכָה, מְלַמְּדִין אוֹתוֹ שֶׁלֹּא יִשְׁחֶה. which is in SA 113:1; 34b discusses הודאה תָּנֵי חֲדָא: הַכּוֹרֵעַ בְּהוֹדָאָה, הֲרֵי זֶה מְשׁוּבָּח. וְתַנְיָא אִידָךְ: הֲרֵי זֶה מְגוּנֶּה which is discussed in 113:3

Comment: Quite the name btw

Answer (score 1):

ההיא בהודאה של הלל. פי' בהודו לה' שאומרים בהלל. ההיא בהודאה של ברכת המזון. פירוש על הכל ה' אלהינו אנו מודים לך וכו'. וה"ה דהוה יכול למימר דרבא סבירא לעיל כמתניתא דלעיל [ברכות דף ל"ד סוף ע"א] דאמר בהודאה תחלה וסוף אלא דלא איכפת ליה ואשכחן דכותה. ודוקא בהני הודאות שהן קבועות ותקנום בלא שחיה, אבל אם בא אדם לחדש ולומר תחנונים הרשות בידו לשחות כמה פעמים כמו שמצינו בר' עקיבא שאמרו עליו כשהיה מתפלל בינו לבין עצמו אדם מניחו בזוית זו ומוצאו בזוית אחרת מפני השתחואות והכרעות הילכך בנשמת כל חי כשאנו אומרים ולך לבדך אנחנו מודים אם בא לשחות הרשות בידו לפי שאינו דבר קבוע ואינו חייב לאמרו כמו הלל וברכת מזון אלא מנהג הגאונים ז"ל ואינו אלא שבחים שאנו מוסיפין לכבוד השבת:

https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Berakhot.34b.3

The ritva answers its only limited to tfillos chazal were misaken. (Maybe thats why might apply to kadish like gra) However aleinu wasn't takanas chazal, Meiri says it was said so that it wouldn't look like you're leaving shul in a rush.

However as doubleaa pointed out, this is against the shulchan aruch 281.
The chidushei anshi sheim brachos 34 brings from the maharam, who says its only assur to bow by modim of thanks,(since there's no point in bowing then) not a modim of vidui or accepting the yoke of heaven. But a modim that we mention bowing there's no problem bowing and it's not worse than bowing in middle of brachos on shmonei esrei.
Also a proof SA seems to agree to this since he holds one should bow in kadish.

Comment: But the Shulchan Aruch rejects this opinion (OC 281)

Comment: @DoubleAA thats not clear from there. It could mean in tfillos they were misaken to say. If you take it for its words, it would mean you can't ever bow even if you're not davening. And that's for sure not true.

Comment: It's very very clear he doesn't rule like the source you quoted which says הילכך בנשמת כל חי כשאנו אומרים ולך לבדך אנחנו מודים אם בא לשחות הרשות בידו לפי שאינו דבר קבוע

Comment: @DoubleAA i hear. However there are times we're not noheg like shulchan aruch. Where do we say that in davening?

Comment: It's about halfway through nishmas shabbos morning וְהַזּוקֵף כְּפוּפִים. לְךָ לְבַדְּךָ אֲנַחְנוּ מודִים: אִלּוּ פִינוּ מָלֵא שִׁירָה כַּיָּם. וּלְשׁונֵנוּ רִנָּה כַּהֲמון גַּלָּיו. וְשפְתותֵינוּ שֶׁבַח כְּמֶרְחֲבֵי רָקִיעַ etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Maybe since aleinu comes from the shemoneh esrei of yom kippur, and there we do bow on yom kippur, so we also bow the whole year during aleinu that we must do on yom kippur...Perhaps the bowing we do at aleinu is related to yom kippur"

- Rabbi Hershel Reichman

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: My friend suggested a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

Bowing by ומודים may be mistaken. The reason we bow then is so not to look like a כופר when saying כורעים ומשתחוים (Magen Avraham 132:2). One may indeed need to rise prior to ומודים (outside of shemoneh esrei one may bow when one pleases—הודאה language aside—see Berachos 34a-b).

Alternatively, Meiri (Berachos 34b) differentiates between מודים in Shemoneh esrei and the other הודאה language where bowing is forbidden by explaining that those all mean praise vs the one in shemoneh esrei which means prostration.

> (הכורע בהודאה של הלל ובהודאה של ברכת המזון ר"ל על הכל אנו מודים לך וכו' הרי זה מגונה והודאה של הלל יש מפרשים ונודה לך שיר חדש שבברכת גאולה או כי לך טוב להודות של ברכה אחרונה ויש מפרשים הודו לה' וטעם הדברים שכל הודאה של הלל או של ברכה הוא לשון הודאה אבל מודים שבתפלה הוא לשון השתחואה מענין השתחויתי האמור בציבא כשנתן לו דוד את השדה שתרגמו יונתן מודינא וכו':)

The מודים in aleinu, which immediately follows כורעים ומשתחוים, may similarly connote bowing, thus allowing for the gesture, as in Shemoneh esrei.

(Also see Taz 113:4 who deals with the issue and offers a solution.)

Comment: could you elaborate more on your answer. If you're allowed to bow in other places, why don't you bow during Birkat Hamazon?

Comment: @Zenus See my comments above. Essentially, Taz 113:4 explains that there are two distinct proscriptions regarding bowing. One during shemoneh esrei where it is circumscribed to the beg and end of avos and hodaah; and another when specifically mentioning hodaah even outside shemoneh esrei which includes birchas hamazon.